# Dirty Memory because of CoreAnimation and CG image

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a Problem in my App with the Dirty Memory Size and want to clear out the dirty memory.
[image: Instruments]

My App is growing bigger and bigger. But the main Problem is the `CoreAnimation` and the `CG Image` type. `Memory Tag 70` is beeing cleared thru my Assync Image Load View.

How can i clear CoreAnimation and CG Image from the dirty memory? 57% dirty memory of the resident seems a bit high for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you had not released them, use `CGImageRelease(cgImage)`, `CGPathRelease(path);`, etc. Like:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(fullImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(...));
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

and for core animation's path

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
...
CGPathRelease(path);
```

and so on.

Comment: I am not using `CGImageRef` and the only animations that i use are the navigation transition and a flip transition like this: [UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft) 
                           forView:self.view
                             cache:YES];

Comment: @mariusLAN mum..I think this one will not cause the issue, you'd better post more code where you use the CGImage & Core Animation on your question.

Comment: I am not using CGImage or Core Animations. I am only using the standard `UIImageViews` and the ability to commit animations.

Comment: @mariusLAN oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood your question...But..I still think you need to post more code on your question, such as the declaration of your ivars.. :)

Comment: I have changed a lot in my code. I can clearly determine the CorAnimation Leak, because i didn't use any kind of Names for the Animations and i set the Cache to false. Many deallocs are helping me to get rid of the dirty memory size.

Comment: @mariusLAN so, you've solved? I wonder what's the issue that cause these dirty memory, just forgot to release the ivar?

Comment: yeah i forgot to implement many deallocs and i got a retain cycle in my views. So yeah, i solved it, by releasing ivars ;)